# What are for the trust relationsheep between forests?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows, active-directory

I'm learning about Windows Server 2008 R2.

I was testing the trusts relationship between two different forests. But I haven't understood the purpose and advantages of this?

Can someone orient what is the purpose of this trust relationship?

Comment: Pick up any one of William Stanek's Windows Server Admin books, everything you want to know is there.

Answer (score 2):

Trusts allow for authentication and authorization across domains/forests so that user A from one domain can be granted access to resources in a different domain or forest. Check [this Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773178%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).